# Problemas con DeserializeObject y SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy Serializando una clase de la siguiente manera:

```
string info = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListaInfo[j]);
```

Donde ListaInfo es un viewmodel, pero al intentar Desealizarlo de la siguiente manera

```
InfoViewModel t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<infoViewModel>(info);
```

me lanza un error de stackoverflow debido a que el viewmodel tiene una propiedad como la siguiente:

```
public string FECHA_DIA {
                                get {
                                    return FECHA == null ? "" : FECHA.Value.Day.ToString();                                        
                                }
                                set {
                                    FECHA_DIA = "";
                                }
                            }
```

Como puedo deserializarlo teniendo esa propiedad en el viewModel?

Comment: Te comparti una respuesta para agregar el atributo [JsonIgnore], pero lo que me hace ruido es que tu propiedad FECHA_DIA el SET no lo utilizas, entonces debera ser una propiedad de solo lectura (porque toma solo valores dependiendo de otra que es FECHA). Ademas otra tema es la nomenclatura en mayusculas en la propiedades te dejo este enlace [Nombres de miembros de tipos: Metodos y Propiedades](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members)

Answer (score 2):

Parece que en tu ejemplo la propiedad "FECHA_DIA" no tiene que estar en el proceso de deserializacion porque toma el valor de la propiedad "FECHA".

Entonces, puedes decorar dicha propiedad "FECHA_DIA" con el atributo [JsonIgnore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=net-6.0) para asi no importa si llega algo o no y siempre toda valor

Ejemplo

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string FECHA_DIA
{
        get
        {
            return FECHA == null ? string.Empty : FECHA.Value.Day.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            FECHA_DIA = string.Empty;
        }
}
```

Una recomendacion parece que el SET no lo tienes que colocar o tenerlo, porque no utilizas para devolver el valor de FECHA_DIA en el GET
Quedaria asi tu propiedad no?

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string FECHA_DIA
{
        get
        {
            return FECHA == null ? string.Empty : FECHA.Value.Day.ToString();
        }
}
```